# Arithmetic Derivative inequality

Tags: number-theory

The arithmetic derivative of a prime number is one. The product rule holds as well with $ (a*b)'=a'b+b'a$. 
I am wondering if there is a way to determine when $n' > n$ or $n'<n$. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculate $n'$ by first determining its prime factorisation $\prod_ip_ie^i$. Then $n'=n\sum_i\frac{e_i}{p_i}$. Hence whether $n>n'$ or $n<n'$ may be determined – there is not a way to ascertain the relation without explicitly computing $n'$.

(There are numbers for which $n'=n$. They are precisely the primes raised to themselves: $2^2,3^3,5^5,7^7\dots$)